# Is there any plugin for better viewing of exceptions?

Tags: tools, debugging, visual-studio, plugins

I don’t think that I’m the only one that thinks that Visual Studio exception window is very poor. Trace information lacking formatting and is hardly readable.

- **Is there any plugin or external tool that shows exception information better?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has the [stack trace explorer](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Navigation/stackTraceExplorer.html). And if you follow [this post](http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2011/01/31/easier-debugging-with-resharper-and-the-clipboard/) the copying and pasting is done automatically.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 Great I have Resharper and I didn't know about this!

Comment: Same Amir - I find new shortcuts for r# all the time that i didnt know about.

Comment: @rmx do you know about the keymaps ? http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper50DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf from http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/documentation.html